# Android window manager reporting incorrect physical size

Tags: android, android-windowmanager

I'm running Android Marshmallow with a 1366x768 display, but `adb shell wm size` returns

```
Physical size: 1920x1080
```

If I run `adb shell wm size 1366x768`, then `wm size` returns

```
Physical size: 1920x1080
Override size: 1366x768
```

The hardware config menu of the display shows 1366x768. Is the display wrong about itself? Is Android not correctly detecting the display's dimensions? Is there a way for me to tell who's right without counting the pixels?

Comment: Why do you think the physcial size isn't 1920x1080?  Counting pixels won't help, as it can lie about those (so long as its moving to fewer and not more).

Comment: Because the hardware menu button on the display itself shows a menu that says 1366x768, and it is specced as such by the manufacturer. I trust the display's self-reporting more than Android (I think).

Comment: Then it probably lied in the files which describe the hardware to the Android kernel.

Comment: That makes sense. Do you know where those files are? Maybe that's worth another question.